# python:send class object in socket.sendto()

Tags: python

I want to send a class object in socket.sendto(classObject , (host , port)).

Basically I want to send some more information with the message.How can I do this.

Comment: What kind of object? Who is listening on the other end? What "other information"?

Comment: Can you show us the code you've tried, however broken it might be? That should help us figure out precisely what you are trying to accomplish. Please post relevant attempts on both the sender and receiver side.

Answer (score 1):

You can't. Serialize the data before attempting to send it.

Answer (score 1):

Use `bits = pickle.dumps(classObject)` to send data into `socket.sendto(bits , (host , port))`.
And use `classObject = pickle.loads(bits)` to get the object after.